# Make site not searchable and not accesible

Tags: search

I recently marked some sites as "No Access" with this powershell script:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631148(v=office.14).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631148%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Set-SPSite -Identity "" -LockState "No Access"

However in a content search webpart we have that  returns items from an info list inside each site, the results are still returned.  Is that normal? I guess the crawler should pick up this and remove it from the search?

Or how else can I do, to :
1. Dont delete the site
2. THey shouldnt appear in search (anything inside the entire site collecttion)

thx

Comment: Have you done a full crawl since setting this as no access? Have you tried going into search admin and making an exclusion?

Comment: I havent run a full crawl, but continuous crawl is enabled. our full crawl takes like 20 hours, if I have to do that eveery time I put a site with no access, that would be very bad

Comment: the query rules, is a good thing though, I will check on monday if the site still appears on results

Comment: Continuous crawl functions much like the incremental crawl afaik, there are things that need a full crawl to sort out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically if a site is marked No Access, then this site is locked for everybody include search crawler.
But if you still getting the result so, make sure full crawl run after locking the site collection.

But even after this you getting the results on the search, try to click the link and see the behavior...

another solution is, exclude that site collection from search using the query rule.
here is couple of links to guide you.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a692238c-3e2c-46e9-818c-e5e8f9ca1308/exclude-a-site-from-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013

http://techmikael.blogspot.no/2013/04/limiting-search-results-in-sharepoint.html